# Converting "manager" style classes to free functions in C++/DirectX11

Tags: c++, directx-11

I have recently run in to a design issue in some of my code using DX11/C++. I'm building a small voxel editor and so far everything works but there are some design issues with some of my code.

Currently I'm having trouble organizing my compute shaders. There are various compute shaders for individual problems. For example: some paint new blocks in to voxels, others smooth the voxel, another implements marching cubes to create the mesh for the voxel, etc, etc. Here is the snippet that has me questioning a great deal of my design:

```
auto voxelInput = voxel::sphere(width, height, depth, center, radius);

auto kernel = voxel::kernel::separable::average(9);
auto smoother = voxel::kernel::processor();

smoother.apply(voxelInput, kernel); 

auto build = marchingCubes::builder<mesh::triangle<vertex::light>, vertex::light>();

return build.mesh(voxelInput, radius/2.f, v3::Zero());
```

The specific issues I have are the marchingCubes::builder and voxel::kernel::processor classes. I know these are wrong, all they do is compile and hold pointers to the shader code. I think they should be converted to free functions and just be called like this:

```
voxel::kernel::apply(voxelInput, kernel);

return marchingCubes::mesh(voxelInput, radius/2.f, v3::Zero());
```

I know of a couple ways that I can solve this problem:

1) Every time either function is called, I compile the necessary shaders (This is the easiest, will get me the end result, but be the ugliest and will have me compiling/deleting shaders frequently, especially if I batch a bunch of voxel operations at once).

2) Use a singleton to create the class at the top of the function. I'm no longer recompiling every time but now I've lost the ability to delete the object easily. What happens when I want to load another completely different module that doesn't use any of the voxel functionality? If I keep loading modules like this, then I potentially have a ton of pointless shaders floating around in memory that I am no longer using.

3) Make a voxel class that has all this functionality built in. Call voxel.applyKernel(krnl), voxel.paint(position), voxel.mesh(args), etc. I don't like this because I'm afraid it will make my voxel class bloated and tedious to work with. I would probably have to store a shared_ptr to the shader amongst all voxels. This solves my memory issue but creates a new design problem of having a monolithic omni class.

4) Some sort of compute shader manager higher up in my engine. It would behave like a singleton, but I could potentially make calls back to it to delete the shader when the voxel module is unloaded. I get the free functions and the ability to delete the shaders when I want. Adding more functionality (like the painter) will be a easier. There are some issues like someone forgetting to remove the shaders when they destroy a module. Or someone calling for deletion, but there is still another module using the free functions. The last one could probably be solved with some kind of reference counter/smart pointer, but I'm not sure this is correct either. It would probably be a fair amount of work and I think I'm just moving the problem somewhere else.

5) Keep the same style of classes, but initialize them when the voxel module gets created. This is the easiest, and the simplest but I'm still left with these weird classes. All I've done is move the problem again. There are less chances for errors this way, but potentially duplicated shader code if another module makes use of some of the functionality (Should be a small amount).

All of the above options technically work, but none feel correct. I'd like to know if someone has a better option that I haven't considered?

Comment: Why not follow an object pool pattern to store the shaders you're using, and use a factory pattern to instantiate new shaders?

You could use this to create seperate pools with groups of shaders you want to use in specific scenarios, and then release individual shaders or the entire pool when you no longer need them.

When you need new shaders, call the factory to build x shader for you, and place it in the shader pool. SIngletons are great for storing configuration stuff, but this doesn't strike me as a good use case.

Comment: @Scube Steve The object pool seems like a great idea for the duplicate shader issue. The factory sounds like it would become pretty troublesome to maintain. My program has quite a few shaders, so one large factory would be hard to keep from triggering large compiles and many small factories sounds like quite a bit of work. But thanks so much for the help.

Comment: For sure, you know the use-case better than I; I don't have any experience with DX11, but glad at least some of that was useful.

Comment: I would counter your point that maybe you have a series of factories that inherit:

ShaderFactory as your base class. And then child classes like 'SmootherFactory' and 'KernalApplyFactory'.

But depending on how much work it is to instantiate a shader directly, an anonymous initializer might be more than enough: ie. shaderPool.Add(new Shader())

Comment: As a final remark, the factory pattern can be useful, but I don't like to obfuscate the instantiation of objects if it can be helped. At the end of the day, the factory can be way way overused, so definitely only use if it's called for. 

Sounds like you have an idea that it may not be, in this case.

Comment: I don't think the factory is correct for this. Instantiating different shaders isn't that hard. There aren't many arguments and I already made some helper functions to do that. All I really need is the path to where they are located. So I think the add function you posted is much closer. I may even be able to get away with a map and use the filepath as a key. I'm going to keep mulling it over and tackle it tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: Anytime. You may also want to know there's a software engineering stack exchange. This question would be a good candidate for that forum - you may get a more diverse set of opinions there.

Comment: @ScubaSteve when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)